# Merging three Express web apps?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to merge three small, separate Express.js apps (with separate functionality/sockets) into one application by creating a landing page with three buttons that will redirect to each while passing some context. Each individual app has a server.js file that will serve its own client-side files.

server.js example:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const httpServer = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {cors: {origin: "*"}});

io.on("connection", socket => { 
    // socket events
});

app.use(express.static("public"));

httpServer.listen(3000, () => {
   console.log("Server running on port 3000.")
});
```

I'm thinking of creating a "main" server that specifies routes to each individual app (e.g. app.get('/app1), app.get('/app2) ...)  but I'm not really piecing together how to execute the server.js file in each of the individual apps upon navigation. Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you want to write a reverse proxy. I recommend servers like [Nginx](https://nginx.org/en/) or [Traefik](https://traefik.io/) for this. Usually, it's easier and better to create multiple, small microservice instead of one large monolith.

Comment: As @jabaa said a reverse proxy could accomplish this safe and better but you could go the hacky way and create 3 different node instances and point them to a particular port in your code  or just use the router to separate them

Comment: @jabaa Thanks, I read up on Nginx and I think I got the gist of it. Would you mind telling me if the following structure makes sense or sounds off? First, create a homepage with three buttons that will redirect to one of three routes (localhost/1, localhost/2, localhost/3). Then, in the nginx.conf file, redirect localhost/1 to port 3000, localhost/2 to port 4000, and localhost/3 to port 5000.  Finally, start up the express servers to listen on ports 3000, 4000, and 5000.

Comment: A redirect is an HTTP response code or a JavaScript function changing the URL: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections You want to proxy/route the requests: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/ resp. https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/routers/